# Typescript doesn't recognize common object for styles in MUI styled component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I have some different styled component with some common styles, so I've created a function that takes in `theme` and returns the common styles.
It looks something like this:

```js
const getCommonStyled = (theme: Theme) => ({
  height: '100%',
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
})

const StyledComponent1 = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  ...getCommonStyled(theme),
  color: 'blue'
}))

const StyledComponent2 = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  ...getCommonStyled(theme),
  backgroundColor: 'blue'
}))

const StyledComponent3 = styled('span')(({ theme }) => ({
  ...getCommonStyled(theme),
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
}))
```

This seems simple enough, but Typescript will not allow it and its error message is confusing:

> error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type '({ theme }: MUIStyledCommonProps & ClassAttributes & HTMLAttributes & { ...; }) => { ...; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TemplateStringsArray'.

How can I type `getCommonStyled` so that these errors go away?

Comment: Please verify that you can reproduce the problem with the exact code specified in your question -- I cannot. I suspect that something additional (represented by `// etc` in your question) is needed to reproduce it.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I have updated the `getCommonStyled` to be the exact same styled used in my actual code.

Comment: And on that note, I am having another similar instance having the same issue with the same TS error, which is `const breakWord = { wordBreak: 'break-word', wordWrap: 'break-word' }`. It doesn't like either those...

Comment: `flexDirection` is the important piece that was missing from the code you originally posted. I'll answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't explicitly specify the return type for `getCommonStyled`, TypeScript is inferring the following:

```
const getCommonStyled: (theme: Theme) => {
     height: string;
     display: string;
     flexDirection: string;
     padding: string; 
}
```

This works fine for any CSS properties where the TypeScript definition allows string values, but the definition for `flexDirection` is more specific:

From https://github.com/frenic/csstype/blob/v3.1.2/index.d.ts#L18882:

```
export type FlexDirection = Globals | "column" | "column-reverse" | "row" | "row-reverse";
```

The way I would recommend fixing this is to specify a return type of `React.CSSProperties`:

```
const getCommonStyled = (theme: Theme): React.CSSProperties => ({
  height: '100%',
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  padding: theme.spacing(2),
})
```

`React.CSSProperties` leverages the `csstype` package as does MUI's [types for the styled API](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-styled-engine/src/index.d.ts#L1) so MUI will recognize a spread of that type as compatible. Specifying that return type will also do more immediate type checking of that method (e.g. you'll get a TypeScript error directly in `getCommonStyled` if you set `flexDirection` to something other than one of the allowed values).

Comment: this works perfectly! Thanks so much for the extra explanation as to why this happens to certain  styles :)